# Pandas Windowing with Groupby not Working as Expected

Tags: python, pandas, windowing

I have a pandas dataframe for which I'm trying to compute an expanding windowed aggregation after grouping by columns. The data structure is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,2015,4],['A',1,2016,5],['A',1,2017,6],['B',1,2015,10],['B',1,2016,11],['B',1,2017,12],
               ['A',1,2015,24],['A',1,2016,25],['A',1,2017,26],['B',1,2015,30],['B',1,2016,31],['B',1,2017,32],
              ['A',2,2015,4],['A',2,2016,5],['A',2,2017,6],['B',2,2015,10],['B',2,2016,11],['B',2,2017,12]],columns=['Typ','ID','Year','dat'])\
.sort_values(by=['Typ','ID','Year'])
```

i.e.

```
    Typ ID  Year    dat
0   A   1   2015    4
6   A   1   2015    24
1   A   1   2016    5
7   A   1   2016    25
2   A   1   2017    6
8   A   1   2017    26
12  A   2   2015    4
13  A   2   2016    5
14  A   2   2017    6
3   B   1   2015    10
9   B   1   2015    30
4   B   1   2016    11
10  B   1   2016    31
5   B   1   2017    12
11  B   1   2017    32
15  B   2   2015    10
16  B   2   2016    11
17  B   2   2017    12
```

I need to group this dataframe by the columns `Type` and `ID`, then compute an expanding mean of the all observations by `Year`. The code I've written is

```
df.groupby(by=['Typ','ID','Year']).expanding().mean().reset_index()
```

from which I expect output results like this (ignoring `level_3`):

```
    Typ ID  Year    level_3 dat
0   A   1   2015    6   14.0
1   A   1   2016    7   14.5
2   A   1   2017    8   15.0
3   A   2   2015    12  4.0
4   A   2   2016    13  4.5
5   A   2   2017    14  5.0
6   B   1   2015    9   20.0
7   B   1   2016    10  20.5
8   B   1   2017    11  21.0
9   B   2   2015    15  10.0
10  B   2   2016    16  10.5
11  B   2   2017    17  11.0
```

Grouping by `['Type','ID','Year']` should result in a single row for each unique row of these columns. Instead, the code is giving this:

```
Typ ID  Year    level_3 dat
0   A   1   2015    0   4.0
1   A   1   2015    6   14.0
2   A   1   2016    1   5.0
3   A   1   2016    7   15.0
4   A   1   2017    2   6.0
5   A   1   2017    8   16.0
6   A   2   2015    12  4.0
7   A   2   2016    13  5.0
8   A   2   2017    14  6.0
9   B   1   2015    3   10.0
10  B   1   2015    9   20.0
11  B   1   2016    4   11.0
12  B   1   2016    10  21.0
13  B   1   2017    5   12.0
14  B   1   2017    11  22.0
15  B   2   2015    15  10.0
16  B   2   2016    16  11.0
17  B   2   2017    17  12.0
```

The `expanding()` windowing function does not seem to be working with the `groupby` correctly, or at least it is not behaving as I expect, given the logic. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I see now what I'm doing wrong, in that I was expecting different integration between `groupby` and `expanding`. So now my question is how can I use pandas to get the output I want - without any manual iteration.

Comment: it is not working probably because it needs certain 'window' to perform the `sum`. by default the window is 1, so it is increasing the window one at a time & adding. if you change the window to 2, you get the sum of 2 rows, but the groups with only 1 value & the fist value in each group will have a value 'NaN'

Comment: Hm, but that is then inconsistent with the `groupby`...

Comment: I beg to differ. If you `groupby' just Typ & & then do expanding om 'DAT' you will see sum adding up (if you change the window you can see the difference).

Comment: Well, maybe I'm really missing something, but as I see, the `df.groupby(by=['Typ','ID','Year'])` at the beginning should force a result of 1 row for each unique `Typ`+`ID`+`Year`...

Comment: the window to calculate `sum()` is 1, not the number of results. The next increment is 2(1+1), so, it gives the sum of 2 rows. if the window is 2, it will calculate the `sum()` of minimum 2 rows, then 4(2+2), then 6(2+2+2) & so on.

Comment: Thanks, I see and understand better. I've edited the question.

Comment: Added an answer, please check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding mean to my knowledge has a different calculation way. For the output you want, I would do the following using a combination of `groupby` and `cumsum`, and later a simple division between `sum` and `count`:

```
newDf = df.groupby(['Typ','ID','Year'])['dat'].agg(('sum', 'count')).groupby(['Typ','ID']).cumsum()
newDf['dat'] = newDf['sum']/newDf['count']
newDf = newDf.reset_index().drop(['count', 'sum'], axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
   Typ  ID  Year   dat
0    A   1  2015  14.0
1    A   1  2016  14.5
2    A   1  2017  15.0
3    A   2  2015   4.0
4    A   2  2016   4.5
5    A   2  2017   5.0
6    B   1  2015  20.0
7    B   1  2016  20.5
8    B   1  2017  21.0
9    B   2  2015  10.0
10   B   2  2016  10.5
11   B   2  2017  11.0
```

Comment: This is a nice use of cumsum. I'm not sure if I should make this as a completely separate question, but I should clarify that I want a solution that will work for other metrics - specifically median & std.

Comment: Perhaps you could make it into a separate question if there is a "one-solution-fits-all" because this answers only your current question here I suppose. I wouldnt be surprised if you have to write your custom function. However, since you asked for a pandas solution, I could just think of this one. Nevertheless, glad to know you found it to be a nice user of cumsum :)